# Is there any way to make a form for Admin to change his username and password stored in credential tag?

Tags: asp.net

I have used the credential tag in web.config file to authenticate my admin. now I want to know is there any way to make a page with a form for admin to change his username and password?
this is my code in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <sessionState cookieless="AutoDetect" mode="InProc"  timeout="114400">
    </sessionState>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms timeout="1440" loginUrl="~/entrance_before_paying.aspx" defaultUrl="Admin/Default.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSDEMO"  cookieless="AutoDetect" protection="All">
            <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
                <user name="elmiragolshanff@yahoo.com"  password="elmira" />
            </credentials>
        </forms>
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

I used this code in my sign in page to check if the user is admin or not:

```
private void enter()
{
    if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(TextBox1.Text.Trim(), TextBox2.Text.Trim())) 
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage("admin user name in credential tag", true);
    }
    else
    {
       // enter as a user}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this code now it works fine

```
<form ID="form1"  runat="server">
   <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnWrite" runat="server" onclick="btnWrite_Click" Text="Modify" />
</div>
```

in   ChangePassword.aspx.cs:

```
  protected void btnWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    Configuration webconfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/wite your site name");
    SystemWebSectionGroup sysweb = (SystemWebSectionGroup)webconfig.GetSectionGroup("system.web");
    AuthenticationSection authSection = sysweb.Authentication;
    FormsAuthenticationUserCollection users = authSection.Forms.Credentials.Users;
    FormsAuthenticationUser user = users[0];
    user.Name = txtUsername.Text;
    user.Password = txtPassword.Text;
    webconfig.Save();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do it this way

```
  <location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="ram"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Use above code in web.config file. this will allow only user 'ram' to access inside 'Admin' folder.